# I am not able to create report server project in my visual studio 2012

Tags: visual-studio-2012, sql-server-2014

I have visual studio 2012  and SQL Server 2014 installed in my machine. As a part of my work I require to open and RDL (SSRS) file in design view. When I checked in the google I saw that I need to have SQL Server Report Services in my visual studio and open Report Server Project. But I am not able to create Report Server Project and I doubt that I don't have SQL Server Report Services in my visual studio.

Comment: Do you have the Business Intelligence template installed in VS?

Comment: No I don't, will it resolve the issue?

Comment: @JacobH thanks man it worked.

Answer (score 1):

I downloaded and installed  Microsoft SQL Server Data Tools - Business Intelligence for Visual Studio 2012 from the location [here](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=36843) (if you VS is 2012). Then I created an new report server project [Report Server Project](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Mhpxg.png) and I did "add Existing Item" as my RDL report which need to be opened and go for design view. Then it will open the report in design mode.